System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors when trying to dynamically add errors to a field
Context:

I am using an external API to perform validation on a record.
It returns a list of fields along with error messages on each field.
The goal is to display these errors alongside the field just like a adding a Validation Rule would.

Approach:
global with sharing class Validation{

    @InvocableMethod (description='Calls external validation API')
    global static void callValidationAPI(Id recordId) {

    // Fetch SObject using Record ID
    // Call API
    // Parse response
    // Add errors if any:
    sobj.addError(fieldName, message);
}

Expectation:

The error is persisted to that field. Whenever a user opens that record, the error is shown.

Problem:
System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors

Question:

In the Winter '21 Release new addError() methods were added.
Can these be used outside of Triggers? Example suggests this should be possible.
If not, what's the best way to achieve my goals?


addError does work outside of triggers (e.g. Visualforce, or even execute anonymous). This error occurs specifically when a record is not able to add an error, such as using Trigger.old in an update trigger (you must use Trigger.new records if they exist). Your problem is that you queried the record, rather than using the original record. Within a DML operation, only the original Trigger.old/Trigger.new/$Record/$Record__Prior records permit errors, and Trigger.old/$Record__Prior only if Trigger.new/$Record are not populated in that context (e.g. in a before delete trigger, you can use Trigger.old).
As a simple proof of concept, I wrote this:
public class ValidateError {
    @InvocableMethod public static void addError(Account[] input) {
        for(Account record: input) {
            record.addError(Account.Name, 'No Account For You');
        }
    }
}

Then passed in the value {!$Record} to the action. This works correctly.
Here's the flow:


Thanks, that is helpful.
My next problem is that I want to make the class generic and not tied to a specific Object. So, record-triggered flows are not an option. Currently, I am using a screen flow that is called on a button press.

@HellChranos1 You can use sObject to allow it to work with any type of record. My example was only built to be quick. Record-triggered flows are how you'd show the error. If you need it to be a screen flow, you can't use addError, because the record's fields aren't directly linked to the flow's variables anyways. Instead, you'd need to make some kind of custom return value to show any errors.
